# How can I display a shared label on button click using highstocks?

Tags: highcharts

I am using D3 and Highstocks to produce a set of linked trends. I have produced a radar chart in D3 with a HTML5 range slider allowing you to travel along the timeseries.

My html5 range slider has the date value in milliseconds.

I can highlight the points in Highstocks like this:

```
vibChart.highcharts().series[0].data[index].setState('hover');
vibChart.highcharts().series[1].data[index].setState('hover');
vibChart.highcharts().series[2].data[index].setState('hover');
vibChart.highcharts().series[3].data[index].setState('hover');
vibChart.highcharts().series[4].data[index].setState('hover');
```

But I would also like to display my shared tooltip for all the series. How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
vibChart.highcharts().tooltip.refresh([vibChart.highcharts().series[1].points[index]]);
```

Comment: If you have shared tooltip, then it suppose to work. If you have `shared: false`, then there should be `tooltip.refresh(point)`, not `tooltip.refresh([point, point, ... , point])`.

Comment: I have this config: tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      crosshairs: true
    }

Comment: So it should work. Could you copy&paste errors from JS console? Or better, recreate issue (like jsFiddle)? Maybe you are trying to display tooltip for non existing points?

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, I think I am onto something. I will come back with a fiddle if I am wrong.